# Execution of code in <script>

Tags: javascript, html

When does the execution of code on  tags begin? Is it sequential?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Canvas tutorial</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function draw(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');
    if (canvas.getContext){
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
  }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="draw();">
<canvas id="tutorial" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is a working piece of code. Why is script above the canvas element?

Comment: *"Why is script above the canvas element?"* Obvious answer: Because the person who wrote the code put it there. In this case it doesn't matter where the script is placed.

Comment: The script should be in the head tag because it will be loaded first when the page is opened. Also javascript is built in client side. You can put script above the body close tag </body> as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple choices for where to put script functions that will be called later.

1. In the `<head>` section.  Scripts here will be available immediately and can be used by any other scripts that are executed while the document is being loaded.
2. In the `<body>` section mixed in with the HTML.  These scripts will be executed at the time that location in the document is parsed.  Everything that comes before the script in the DOM will be in place and ready.  Everything that comes after the script will not yet be available.
3. At the very end of the body, right before the `</body>` tag.  At the time these scripts execute, the whole document before it will be ready.

In your particular case, a function is defined in the `<head>` section so that it is available for execution at some later time.  Because of the way the code appears in the `<head>` section, that code is only a function definition.  Nothing actually executes when that code is parsed.  The function itself is then executed when the page and its images are done loading via the onload handler specified in this line:

```
<body onload="draw();">
```

Only then is the code actually called and run.  The `draw()` function could have been defined in any of the above three locations for this particular issue because the onload handler comes after all three options.  As to why the script is above the canvas element, that is just a choice the designer of the page made.  They could have located the script after the canvas element if they wanted and the page would have still worked fine.

A good working practice is to place scripts as late in the `<body>` as possible because that allows the page content to load and display quicker.  But, some scripts are needed during the creation of the page (for example scripts that choose to use `document.write()`) so they must be placed earlier so they are available when needed.  Scripts may also be marked `defer` or `async` to further delay their loading to allow content to be displayed first.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method is to put your scripts right below the closing body tag.

However, if it's essential to use a script on a page right away, it's best to keep it in the header.

Comment: I guess the follow up question would be: What is deemed to be an "essential" use case?

Answer (score 1):

Because the script merely defines a function that does not get invoked until the page is completely loaded (via the `onload` body attribute).

Answer (score -1):

Inline elements will execute sequentially, as is the case in your example.  However, all your current code does is define a function.  It does not execute that function.

In your case you utilized the `body onload=` event to actually execute the draw() function.  This is why you do not have a problem with the code, which seems to be the point of your initial question.

For this reason, it is typically recommended that you not place javascript in the head section unless absolutely necessary, and instead place it as close to closing body tag as possible.

With that said, in this case you define a function, but defining it and executing it are 2 different things.  It is not a problem for you to define a function that you do not execute until the DOM is ready, and the DOM element(s) you want to work with are already rendered.

With that said, when you load external javascript files in the head section, it can cause the rendering of the page to block, and depending on the size and number of scripts you're loading that way, it's again advisable to place these at the end of the page.  This will avoid the concerns you have in terms of the existence of DOM elements prior to execution of a function that attempts to manipulate those elements.

Comment: Scripts defined in the head section are not automatically deferred.  You can put a `window.location = "http://www.google.com";` in the head section and it will execute right away.  If you want scripts deferred until the document loads, then you have to define the scripts there so that they will not execute until you want them to.  That is not an automatic feature of the `<head>` section.

Comment: @jfriend00, agreed.  I improved the answer by addressing inline script, which I really should have done in the first place.

Comment: But, your first sentence is just wrong.  Scripts loaded in the `<head>` section are not automatically deferred.  They are executed in the order parsed just like any other javascript.  If all they do is define functions (as in this case), then nothing happens except functions are defined.  If they actually do something, then that code is executed at the time it is parsed (it is not deferred like you say).

Comment: @jfriend00, yes thanks for calling me on that.  I wanted to make a point about blocking and did a lousy job of it.

Answer (score -1):

Do no use an `onload` attribute on the `body` element...in fact don't use any attributes on the `body` element ever.

```
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function() {/*load multiple functions here*/}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
```